# Move background image or foreground image

Tags: html, css

```js
//<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#accordion li").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   var subList = $(this).find('> ul');
   if(subList.length) subList.slideToggle(300);
   });
  });
  //]]>
```

```css
html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color:#000;
    text-align:justify;
    background-image: url('../inc/pg/3.png'), url('../inc/pg/4.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:left bottom, right bottom;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
P {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    color:#000;
    font-family:Tahoma;
}
h1 {
    font: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.875em;
    background-color: #93A6A6;
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    word-spacing: normal;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9, h10, h11, h12 {
    font:normal 15px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #93A6A6;
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
div#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width:600px;
    width:1200px;
    margin:0px auto;
    border: 10px double #005cc6;
}
div#banner {
    padding:10px;
    background: url('header.png') no-repeat center center;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
}
div#nav_main {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    width: 1180px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
div#social {
    position: absolute;
    float:right;
}
div#image {
 background-image: url('http://oi61.tinypic.com/aakub6.jpg'); 
 background-position:-10px -50px; 
 height:80px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
div#uscite {
    padding:30px 20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    border:0px;
    height:35%;
    width:20%;
}
div#jp {
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    border:0px;
}
div#it {
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    border:0px;
}
div#navigation_left {
    float: left;
    width:22%;
}
div#navigation_right {
    float: right;
    width:20%;
}
div#content {
    padding: 16px 10px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-left:17%;
    margin-right:17%;
}
div#footer {
    clear:both;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #444444;
    background: url('footer.png') no-repeat center center;
    height:70px;
}
div#back_top {
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
    border:0px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#0066FF;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
a:hover {
    color: #0066FF;
    text-decoration: underline
}
#accordion {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#accordion li {
    display: block;
    /*background-color: #8bc1dd;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 7px;
}
#accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
#accordion ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
#accordion a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion a:hover {
    color: #0066FF;
    text-decoration: underline
}
#accordion ul li a:hover {
    padding-left: 60px;
    color: #8484fc;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: url(bullet.png) left no-repeat;
}
div#language {
    padding-top:10px
}
#nav_main div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.blockspoiler {
    padding:7px;
    background-color:#ffde00;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:14px;
}
.blockspoiler2 {
    padding:7px;
    background-color:#c86565;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:14px;
}
.blockspoiler3 {
    padding:7px;
    background-color:#8991db;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:14px;
}
.nav_main {
    background:url(../img/nav_main.png);
}
.nav {
    heigh:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.home {
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    width: 111px;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.staff {
    background-position: -0px -50px;
    width: 126px;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.forum {
    background-position: -0px -100px;
    width: 136px;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.disclaimer {
    background-position: -0px -150px;
    width: 243px;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.secret {
    background-position: -0px -200px;
    width: 257px;
    height: 38px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.bandiere {
    background:url(../img/flag.png);
}
.flag {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.flag_en {
    background-position:-0px -0px;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.flag_es {
    background-position:-0px -58px;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.flag_fr {
    background-position:-0px -116px;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.flag_de {
    background-position:-0px -174px;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.flag_jp {
    background-position:-0px -232px;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.icon {
    background:url(../img/icone.png);
}
.advice {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.chrome {
    background-position:-0px -0px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.firefox {
    background-position:-0px -80px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.facebook {
    background-position:-0px -160px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.twitter {
    background-position:-0px -240px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.affiliazioni {
    background:url(../img/gemellati.png);
}
.gemellati {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.banner_1 {
    background-position:-0px -0px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_2 {
    background-position:-0px -41px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_3 {
    background-position:-0px -82px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_4 {
    background-position:-0px -123px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_5 {
    background-position:-0px -164px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_6 {
    background-position:-0px -205px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.affiliazioni2 {
    background:url(../img/net.png);
}
.net {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.banner_7 {
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    width: 88px;
    height: 31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_8 {
    background-position: -0px -41px;
    width: 88px;
    height: 31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_9 {
    background-position:-0px -82px;
    width: 88px;
    height: 31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_10 {
    background-position:-0px -123px;
    width: 88px;
    height: 31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_11 {
    background-position:-0px -164px;
    width: 88px;
    height: 31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_12 {
    background-position:-0px -205px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_13 {
    background-position:-0px -246px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_14 {
    background-position:-0px -287px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_15 {
    background-position:-0px -328px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_16 {
    background-position:-0px -369px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_17 {
    background-position:-0px -410px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_18 {
    background-position:-0px -451px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_19 {
    background-position:-0px -492px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_20 {
    background-position:-0px -533px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_21 {
    background-position:-0px -574px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.banner_22 {
    background-position:-0px -615px;
    width:88px;
    height:31px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div#language{padding-top:10px}
#nav_main div{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Full Metal Panic Italy - Home</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="it" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
 <meta name="keywords" content="full, metal, panic, fmp, fumoffu, the second raid, spoiler, mithril, amalgam, sigma" />
 <meta name="description" content="Full Metal Panic Italy, sito ufficiale italiano di Full Metal Panic con spoiler, informazioni, curiosità e molto altro! Fanart, immagini, download e schede tecniche" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../inc/style.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../inc/js/prototype.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../inc/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../inc/js/lightbox.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../inc/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
 <style type="text/css">
  div#language{padding-top:10px}
  #nav_main div{display:inline-block;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="banner"><div id="uscite"><div id="jp"><img src="../img/uscite/scan.png" height="90" width="60" alt="" /><br />uscite jappo</div>
<div id="it"><img src="../img/uscite/scan.png" height="90" width="60" alt="" /><br />uscite ita</div></div>
<div id="social">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/fmpitaly"><img src="../img/facebook.png" width="70" height="70" title="Vieni a trovarci su Facebook" alt="Facebook" /></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/FMP_Italy"><img src="../img/facebook.png" width="70" height="70" title="Vieni a trovarci su Twuitter" alt="Twitter" /></a>
</div>
<div id="image">
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function image() {
};

image = new image();
number = 0;
// imageArray

image[number++] = "<img src='../inc/pg/1.png' height='350' width='204' alt='' />"
image[number++] = "<img src='../inc/pg/2.png' height='350' width='232' alt='' />"
image[number++] = "<img src='../inc/pg/3.png' height='350' width='176' alt='' />"
image[number++] = "<img src='../inc/pg/4.png' height='350' width='270' alt='' />"
image[number++] = "<img src='../inc/pg/5.png' height='350' width='290' alt='' />"

increment = Math.floor(Math.random() * number);
//-->
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
document.write(image[increment]);
</script>

</div>
<div id="nav_main">
 <div style="margin-right:50px"><a href="?page=index"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" height="1" class="nav_main nav home" border="0" title="Home" alt="Home" /></a></div>
 <div style="margin-right:50px"><a href="?page=staff"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" height="1" class="nav_main nav staff" border="0" title="Staff" alt="Staff" /></a></div>
 <div style="margin-right:50px"><a href="../forum"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" height="1" class="nav_main nav forum" border="0" title="Forum" alt="Forum" /></a></div>
 <div style="margin-right:50px"><a href="?page=disclaimer"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" height="1" class="nav_main nav disclaimer" border="0" title="Dislaimer" alt="Dislaimer" /></a></div>
 <div style="margin-right:50px"><a href="?page=restricted"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" height="1" class="nav_main nav secret" border="0" title="Top Secret" alt="Top Secret" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
   <div id="navigation_left"><div id="language" align="center">
<a href="http://goo.gl/2S0bS"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" border="0" height="1" class="bandiere flag flag_en" title="English Translation" alt="English Translation"/></a>
<a href="http://goo.gl/l3ohy"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" border="0" height="1" class="bandiere flag flag_es" title="Spanish Translation" alt="Spanish Translation"/></a>
<a href="http://goo.gl/on3Or"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" border="0" height="1" class="bandiere flag flag_fr" title="French Translation" alt="French Translation"/></a>
<a href="http://goo.gl/b3MKz"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" border="0" height="1" class="bandiere flag flag_de" title="German Translation" alt="German Translation"/></a>
<a href="http://goo.gl/Kh44L"><img src="../img/transparent.gif" width="1" border="0" height="1" class="bandiere flag flag_jp" title="Japanese Translation" alt="Japanese Translation"/></a>
</div>
<ul id="accordion">
 <li><div id="image" align="center"><img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2pq45ys.jpg" height="" width="" alt="Storia"/></div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../fmp/?page=fmp_trama">Full Metal Panic!</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=fumoffu_trama">Full Metal Panic? Fumoffu</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=fmptsr">Full Metal Panic! TSR</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=riassunti">Riassunti Episodi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=manga">Manga</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=listamanga">Lista Manga</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=romanzi">Romanzi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=sigma">Sigma</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=overload">Overload</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=comicmission">Comic Mission</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=another">Another</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=sdnefd">SDNED</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=zero">Zero</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=riassunti_manga">Riassunti Manga</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=riassuntiromanzi">Riassunti Romanzi</a></li>  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><div align="center"><img src="../img/spoiler.png" height="" width="" alt="Spoiler" /></div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../fmp/?page=infanziasousuke">Infanzia di Sousuke</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=infanziatessa">Infanzia di Tessa</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=infanziakurz">Infanzia di Kurz</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=lemon">Michel Lemon</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=origini">Le Origini</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=finemithril">Fine della Mirthril</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=yamsuk11">Yamsuk 11</a></li>  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><div align="center"><img src="../img/gallery.png" height="" width="" alt="Gallery" align="center"/></div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../fmp/?page=fanart">FanArt</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=wallpapers">Wallpapers</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=animated">Animated</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=avatars">Avatar</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=cosplay">Cosplay</a></li>  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><div align="center"><img src="../img/interviste.png" height="" width="" alt="Interviste" align="center"/></div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../fmp/?page=perla">Perla Liberatori</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=lapenna">Leslie La Penna</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=intervistavalerio">Valerio Manenti | J-Pop</a></li>  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><div align="center"><img src="../img/other.png" height="" width="" alt="Other" align="center"/></div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../fmp/?page=faq">F.A.Q. e Curiosità</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=episodi">Titoli Episodi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=mithril">Mithril</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=merida">Isola Merida</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=terroristi">Terroristi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=personaggi">Personaggi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=whispered">Whispered</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=bt">Black Tecnology</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=mech">Arm Slave</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=equip">Equipaggiamenti AS</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=tdd">Tuatha De Danaan</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=palladio">Palladio</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=armi">Armi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=lambdadriver">Lambda Driver</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=gatoh">Shouji Gatoh</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=shikidouji">Shiki Douji</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=doppiaggio_ita">Doppiaggio Italiano</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=doppiaggio">Doppiaggio</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=frasi">Frasi Celebri</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=doms">D.O.M.S</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=luoghi">Luoghi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=sicilia">Viaggio a Canicatti</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=tateo">Retsu Tateo</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=filmvsanime">Film Vs Anime</a></li>  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>  
   <div id="navigation_right"><ul id="accordion">
 <li><div align="center"><img src="../img/multimedia.png" height="" width="" alt="Multimedia" /></div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../fmp/?page=soundtrack">Soundtrack</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=testi">Lyric</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=midi">Videosigle</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=trailers">Trailers</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=music_video">Music Video</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=winamp">Skin Winamp</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=nsliveaction">Nostro Live Action</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=dvd_vhs">DVD/VHS</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=shimokawa">Mikuni Shimokawa</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=sahashi">Toshihiko Sahashi</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=chrome">Tema Google Chrome</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=firefox">Tema Firefox</a></li><li><a href="../fmp/?page=app">App Smartphone</a></li>   <li>Link1
    <ul>
     <li>Link2</li>
     <li>Link3</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>        
   <div id="content">
 </div>
   <div id="footer"><div id="back_top"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></div></div>
  </div>
</body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../inc/menu/menu.js"></script>
</html>
```

I have an accordion menu (jquery) where every category is between `li` I want put an image as background to every category and to do so I used a `div`
I need to center the background-image of the div with another image between div like this:
[image]
So I want that this:
[image]
goes on this.
[image]
I tried to move the background but was been cut because goes out `li` or move the foreground
but moves both of them.

```
<div style="background: url('../img/bg.png'); height:80px; right:20px; up:40px" align="center"><img src="../img/storia.png" height="" width="" alt="Storia"/></div>
```

I tried with another approach:
CSS:
    div#image {
        background-image: url('../img/bg.png'); 
        background-position:-10px -50px;
        height:80px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    }
HTML:

```
<div id="image" align="center"><img src="../img/text.png" /></div>
```

but this is the result
[image]
Here all codes:
HTML

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li><div id="image" align="center"><img src="../img/text.png" /></div>
        <ul>
            <?php
                isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
                $links=array(
                    "link" => "Text",
                );
                foreach($links as $href=>$text){
                    if($page!=$links){
                    echo '<li><a href="../fmp/?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a></li>';
                    }else{echo $text;}
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#accordion {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#accordion li {
    display: block;
    /*background-color: #8bc1dd;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 7px;
}
#accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
#accordion ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
#accordion a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion a:hover {
    color: #0066FF;
    text-decoration: underline
}
#accordion ul li a:hover {
    padding-left: 60px;
    color: #8484fc;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: url(bullet.png) left no-repeat;
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: In general, if you add the code to fiddle.js or as a snippet it allows people to troubleshoot the question quicker for you :)

Comment: I'm sorry. There aren't images or other but it works. Menus are under that set of 5 images on the left and there's a menu on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
li {
position:absolute;
margin-right: ? px;
margin-top: ? px;
}
```

Comment: Same here. This is the structure: `<li><ul><li><li>...</ul></li>`. If I edit a li, I will to all of them. That's why I was using div. Is there a way to modify the structure to do these solutions useful?

Comment: You can use pseudo classed for that

Comment: I tried giving on the first `li` an id but crashes everything. Which pseudo-clases? I tried to use `li div#image:first-child`with this html: `<li><div id="image"><img src="../img/storia.png" /></div>` but this is the result: http://oi57.tinypic.com/v5c2g7.jpg
I also tried to use a div in another div but text's image is behind the image that I want as background. I know is wrong the order of div, but contrariwise I can't see the text.
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2n7judi.jpg
`<li><div style="background: url('../img/storia.png') center center no-repeat;"><div id="image"></div></div>`

Comment: I did it! Thanks! I just defined a class to `li` and put the image between a `div` and with that move the image

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the line height in the CSS to ensure it has the same height as the background image? Example below

```
#mynav li {

line-height: 100px;
background: url(100pximage.png) left no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: No I can't. I put a snippet. As you can see, there's a main `li` for the category's title and all other `li` for links. So, even with no-repeat, will be repeat on the other `li`

Comment: @Shika93 can't see with all the broken images?

Comment: Added. On the others just changes text.